# Python: Error al acceso a una ruta de disco que contiene barra invertida (windows)

Tags: python

he hecho un croquis un poco chungo con el Paint para explicar mi problema, al intentar acceder a la ruta de disco "'d:\tmp\2.wav'" con "open", me añade doble barra vertical invertida "'d:\tmp\2.wav'" dando error. Solo me pasa con Windows usando barra invertida, en Linux con barra normal / no me hace estas tonterías. Estoy usando Thonny en ambos sistemas.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu interpretación de lo que está pasando es erróna, pero es un error frecuente.

Lo que ocurre con la barra `\` es fuente inagotable de confusiones entre quienes están empezando. Ocurre que esa barra, cuando aparece dentro de una cadena dentro del código fuente, tiene un significado especial y para descifrar su significado el compilador mira el carácter que aparece detrás de ella. Así, por ejemplo (y este ejemplo seguro que te suena), si en Python (o en C, o Java, o muchos otros lenguajes que comparten este convenio) haces algo como:

```
v = "Hola\n"
```

La cadena almacenada en `v` tendrá 5 caracteres y no 6, ya que los dos últimos `\n` en realidad son convertidos por el compilador a uno solo: el retorno de carro. Aunque en el fuente has tecleado dos caracteres, la barra `\` y la `n`, ya que la barra es "especial", Python mirará el carácter que viene detrás y al ver que es una `n`, entiende que el programador quiso escribir un **n**ewline, y convierte esos dos `\n` a uno solo: el ASCII 13 que es el caracter de nueva línea.

Pero hay veces en las que el programador no querrá que `\` sea especial. Típicamente cuando estás metiendo una ruta en Windows. Imagina esta ruta:

```
ruta = "D:\new_folder\new_file.txt"
```

Cuando python vea el carácter `\` dentro de ella, mirará el siguiente carácter, y resulta ser una `n`, por lo que sustituirá `\n` por el ASCII "nueva línea". Como resultado nuestra ruta estará mal, pues será `"D:<nuevalinea>ew_folder<nuevalinea>ew_file.txt"`

Esto puedes verificarlo si haces:

```
print(ruta)
```

Pues saldrá:

```
D:
ew_folder
ew_file.txt
```

No obstante, si en lugar de imprimir la cadena quieres ver su "representación", entonces la verás de otra forma:

```
print(repr(ruta))
```

---

```
'D:\new_folder\new_file.txt'
```

En este caso Python la muestra tal como habría que introducirla en el código fuente, para que cuando la interprete genere el mismo resultado que antes imprimimos. Esto es un poco confuso, pero fíjate en las comillas alrededor. Cuando Python imprime la **representación** de una cadena, le pone comillas alrededor, y dentro de ella los `\` tendrán ese significado especial.

Para evitar que `\` tenga significado especial, el programador debe escribir la barra dos veces, ya que cuando Python encuentra el primer `\`, mirará qué viene luego y encontrará `\`, de modo que entenderá que el programador quería poner la barra inversa y sustituirá la secuencia `\\` por una sola `\`.

Es decir, tendríamos que haber introducido la ruta así:

```
ruta = "D:\\new_folder\\new_file.txt"
```

La representación de esta cadena es tal como la introdujimos, es decir:

```
print(repr(ruta))
```

---

```
'D:\\new_folder\\new_file.txt'
```

Pero aunque la representación la muestra duplicada, en realidad sólo hay una barra cada vez, como podemos comprobar si imprimimos la cadena en lugar de su representación:

```
print(ruta)
```

---

```
D:\new_folder\new_file.txt
```

### Tu problema

Dicho todo esto, ya estamos en condiciones de interpretar lo que estás viendo en tu programa.

Primero haces un:

```
print(nombre_wav + ".wav")
```

No vemos cómo se ha asignado la variable `nombre_wav`, posiblemente sea texto introducido por el usuario y leido con `input()`. En este caso la barra no tiene ningún significado especial (sólo lo tiene cuando aparece dentro del código fuente, no cuando es leída de otro lugar). Si el usuario teclea una `\`, la cadena tendrá una `\`.

Efectivamente el resultado de ese `print()` muestra todo normal:

```
d:\tmp\2.wav
```

En cambio cuando te pones a abrir ese fichero con `open()` ocurre algún error. **El fichero no existe**. Y cuando Python como parte del mensaje de error te quiere mostrar el nombre del fichero, lo que muestra es *su representación*, pues vemos:

```
'd:\\tmp\\2.wav'
```

Las comillas alrededor nos advierten de que se trata de la representación de una cadena, y en ellas, como ya vimos, el `\` tiene significado especial por lo que Python las muestra duplicadas.

Lo importante aquí es que la doble barra aparece sólo porque Python está mostrando la representación, pero no forma parte de la cadena que realmente tiene una sola barra.

Por tanto el error se debe a que el fichero **realmente no existe**, y no a cosas raras relacionadas con la barra. ¿Has verificado que exista realmente?

Comment: Comprobado, realmente no existía, la automatización en bucle de python no daba tiempo a otro programa que uso en paralelo para generar los .wav